# Исключение нескольких постов из обработки плагином в WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Доброго времени суток.

Существует такой плагин "Auto post scheduler", его функция заключается в обновлении  через заданное время даты поста (всё это тонко настраивается, к примеру, 1 пост за стуки).
Но проблема в том, что у него в настройках полностью отсутствует возможность задать  исключения. Я открыл основной файл плагина [ссылка на него в оф. репозитории](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/auto-post-scheduler/trunk/auto-post-scheduler.php) , увидел там такой код:

```
// set up the basic post query
    $post_types = explode(',', $aps_post_types);

    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'    => $aps_batch,
        'cat'           => $aps_cats,
        'author'        => $aps_authors,
        'post_type'         => $post_types,
        'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true
    );
```

и отредактировал его вот так

```
// set up the basic post query
    $post_types = explode(',', $aps_post_types);

$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => $aps_batch,
    'post__not_in'   => array(827, 809),
    'cat'           => $aps_cats,
    'author'        => $aps_authors,
    'post_type'         => $post_types,
    'ignore_sticky_posts'   => true
);
```

Я ничего не сломал? Действовал методом логики. У плагина есть режим DEBUG и там постоянно при очередном срабатывании строчка в логе выскакивает, указывая эти параметры. Как я понял, это базовые правила, к примеру, исключать "липкие посты". Значит туда можно и вписать исключения для конкретных постов.

Я прав? Я не нарушил логику скрипта? Нет ли каких то подводных камней в применённом мной решении?

Заранее спасибо за ответ, уважаемые специалисты :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы сделали правильно, но при обновлении плагина ваша правка слетит. Специально для таких вещей в WordPress предусмотрены фильтры, и фильтр существует в плагине (строка 753 файла).

Чтобы использовать его, добавьте следующий код в `functions.php` вашей темы:

```
/**
 * Filters aps_eligible_query
 *
 * @param array $args
 *
 * @return mixed
 */
function aps_eligible_query_filter( $args ) {
    $args[ 'post__not_in'] = [ 827, 809];

    return $args;
}

add_filter( 'aps_eligible_query', 'aps_eligible_query_filter' );
```